# How to use bind_rows() and ignore column names

Tags: r, binding, dplyr

This question probably has been answered before, but I can't seem to find the answer. How do you use `bind_rows()` to just `union` the two tables and ignore the column names.
The documentation on `bind_rows()` has the following example:

```
#Columns don't need to match when row-binding
bind_rows(data.frame(x = 1:3), data.frame(y = 1:4))
```

This returns column `x` and `y`. How do I just get a single column back without having to change the column names?
Desired output, I don't really care what the column name ends up being:

```
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
5 2
6 3
7 4
```

Comment: You can't `bind_rows` ignoring column names. `?bind_rows` documentation says, `"When row-binding, columns are matched by name, and any missing columns with be filled with NA."`. Using `bind_rows(unname(df1), unname(df2))` it gives an error `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with a quick 2-line function:

```
force_bind = function(df1, df2) {
    colnames(df2) = colnames(df1)
    bind_rows(df1, df2)
}
force_bind(df1, df2)
```

Output:

```
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
5 2
6 3
7 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we still need change the names here

```
bind_rows(data.frame(x = 1:3), setNames(rev(data.frame(y = 1:4)), names(data.frame(x = 1:3))))
  x
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 1
5 2
6 3
7 4
```